# wrap attributes under custom key active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have serializer like

```
class UserSeriazer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :email
end
```

and the json produced as below

```
{
  name: 'james'
  email: 'j@sample.com'
}
```

how can i wrap the **above** json item, under custom key say `customer`

```
{
  customer:
    {
      name: 'james'
      email: 'j@sample.com'
    }

}
```

I tries something like attribute :name, :email, key: :customer, but didn't work. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add root key to your serializer file. in UserSerializer, add this

```
attributes :name, :email, root: 'customer'
```

I'm not sure of how this would work. You can go with following if this doesn't work.

The best method would be to create a new serializer called CustomerSerializer. That would inherit from UserSerializer. In the derived serializer, you can specify the required attributes. Wherever you user UserSerializer should be modified to use CustomerSerializer.

```
class CustomerSerializer < UserSerializer
  attributes :name , :email
end
```

Please comment which works!